# How to know the command line used by Eclipse to run the java program?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem executing my java sample "hello world" program outside Eclipse while Eclipse can execute it whenever I push the Run menu button. So I want to know the command line Eclipse uses to execute the java program.

Comment: try "java helloworld" in your console where helloworld is your compiled class file ?

Comment: To run your class having main method(...), which is a part of a package. You run it on command prompt like this `java packagename.subpackagenameifany.NameOfTheClassHavingTheMainMethod` Press Enter after writing that.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can check the other parameters `arguments`, `classpath`, `environment variables` etc. that eclipse might be using to compile your program, from the `Run Configurations` window, which appears as a dropdown when you click the drop-down button next to the `Run` button in eclipse.

To get the full command line, you can open the `Debug view` from `Window>Show View>Other...`.  Right click on the last launch and go to properties.  Eclipse will list the exact command line.

Comment: Your edit is a great answer, thank you!  Gives me all the details of classpath and system props set in cmd line.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2019 (version 4.13.0):

```
Eclipse > Run > Run Configurations
```

There is a "**Show Command Line**" button that shows the full command Eclipse uses:

[image: Show command line button for Java Eclipse run configurations window]

Answer (score 3):

The thing is Eclipse uses (by default) different directories for source and object files. If you want to execute a particular java file from the command line, you can either compile it by going inside your workspace directory/src directory and hit `javac <MyClass>.java` and then do `java MyClass`.

Or since it works in eclipse, you can go inside the 'bin' directory inside your workspace and do a `java MyClass` which will execute your pre compiled class.