# How to execute a python configuration that exists in "Run Configurations" Eclipse...from the command line

Tags: python, eclipse, configuration, console

I would like to execute a run configuration using one parameter from my main .py module and others that are given from a run configuration created in Eclipse,
the configuration is run by another .py file called let's say "database.py" with parameters taken from the configuration like so :

-q 
-u
-p 
-c
-f 
-s oracle
-d 
-w yes
-r parameter taken from console of my main run.py
-o

I can run it from Eclipse IDE going to run configurations, but I would like this to be executed if I type "yes" into the console.

Comment: In your launch configuration you can use `${string_prompt:requested value name:optional default value}` in _Arguments_. This will open a dialog which prompts for the input. Or should the _parameter taken from console_ not be entered, but taken from the output from another script?

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477534/how-to-know-the-command-line-used-by-eclipse-to-run-the-java-program). It's for java apps but might give a good idea about how to capture the command executed by Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger I want to be prompted at the console for just a yes/no, then if it is yes execute: C:\Python27\python.exe -u file.py -q -u  -p  -c  -f  -s oracle -d  -w yes -r -o D:\output , with all parameters given of course.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I caputerd the series of commands I want to execute, it is a configuration, but how to I execute it based on a "yes" input on the command line of eclipse.

Comment: If [reading the yes/no from stdin in the Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450393/6505250) does not work, you can wrap the command in an Ant or shell/bash script.