# Error while trying to run java class in cmd - Cannot find the class

Tags: java, cmd

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, so if it doesn't, let me know.

When I try to use the command `java classname` it gives me the error `Cannot find or load main class`, but when i compile it just in Eclipse i don't get that error, the problem is with my cmd.

When i go inside the source directory where my project is which is `C:\Users\hp\eclipse-workspace\ServerMT\bin`, and type "dir" they list that my class is in there, but when i run the command it just doesn't work.

Now I somehow have two versions of java which is jdk-13.0.2 and jdk-15, both inside the programs java folder, i really don't know which one of them to use or each one of them works or if that's the source of the problem.

I kept updating the environment variables switching between ones for jdk-15 and one for jdk-13, nothing works, I really don't know how to solve this, been trying to for a week, any help will be appreciated.

And when i run the command `echo %CLASSPATH%` the result is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\lib*.jar`, but  when I type this in search on my pc I can't find the folder, I only find C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.

Comment: What is the fully qualified domain name of your class? (package name + class name)

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke the package is set to default, the class name is ServerMT

Comment: What is the output of the command : java --version ?

Comment: @YourHelper       output is java version "1.8.0_271"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any environment variables except PATH, which should point to the java version you want.

And especially, don't use CLASSPATH. Thus you prevent the JVM from finding your class in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well many problems can cause this, first thing:

- If your class is inside a package (and it is highly recommended to be this way) then you must write something like `java mypackage.MyClass`, and you must be in root of your classes folders (where `mypackage` folder exists).
- Have you compiled your source files? What do you see there `MyClass.class` or `MyClass.java`?

I think you are a newbie and trying to learn java, if that's the case you probably don't use any library, so CLASSPATH variable is not probably your problem, but it is better to remove CLASSPATH from your environment variables.

Comment: yes i'm new to this,my class isn't inside any package it's just the default package in eclipse, i complied the code and it works on eclipse, when i run it in cmd and check"dir' i see "Myclass,class" but when i try to type java myclass it doesnt work, i deleted the classpath and it stil doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to directory `C:\Users\hp\eclipse-workspace\ServerMT\bin` and enter the following command:

```
java -cp . ServerMT
```

[image: CMD screen capture]

Refer to the documentation for the [java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html)

This question and answer may also be helpful.
[How to know the command line used by Eclipse to run the java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477534/how-to-know-the-command-line-used-by-eclipse-to-run-the-java-program)

In the [package explorer view](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-09/index.jsp) of Eclipse, the project JDK should appear.

[image: Eclipse package explorer view]