# Exception when using '-Djava.system.class.loader' on JDK 11.0.11, if class loader is in signed JAR

Tags: java, classloader, aspectj, java-11, jar-signing

I have problems to start/run an Java application with AspectJ Load-Time-Weaving in Spring Tool Suite 4.11 (based on Eclipse 2021-06) on a Java 11.0.11 Runtime (tested with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11.9-hotspot or Oracle JDK build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 or Zulu11.48+21-CA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS) on Windows 10) when `javax.net.ssl.SSLContext` is accessed. With older Java 11 versions this issue does not occur.
I have reduced the problem to a small application:

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        System.err.println(cp);
        String cn = System.getProperty("java.system.class.loader");
        System.err.println(cn);
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    }
}
```

The app is started in Eclipse with an AspectJ LTW Launch Configuration.
The output and exception I get is this:

```
D:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.weaver_1.9.6.202103162301.jar;D:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.runtime_1.9.6.202103162301.jar
org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.WeavingURLClassLoader

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:248)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:242)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList.tryGet(ProviderList.java:511)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList$1.hasNext(ProviderList.java:565)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getSignature(JsseJce.java:202)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.JsseJce$EcAvailability.<clinit>(JsseJce.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(JsseJce.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:1079)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:941)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:384)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:580)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1918)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1894)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
    at org.pmd.bug.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Here is the full output when I enable Security debug log with VM argument `"-Djava.security.debug="jca"`:

```
ProviderList: provider configuration: [SUN, SunRsaSign, SunEC, SunJSSE, SunJCE, SunJGSS, SunSASL, XMLDSig, SunPCSC, JdkLDAP, JdkSASL, SunMSCAPI, SunPKCS11]
ProviderList: config configuration: null
ProviderList: ThreadLocal providers: [SUN, SunRsaSign, SunEC, SunJCE]
ProviderList: Disabling ThreadLocal providers
ProviderList: ThreadLocal providers: [SUN, SunRsaSign, SunEC, SunJCE]
ProviderList: Loading all providers
java.lang.Exception: Debug Info. Call trace:
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.loadAll(ProviderList.java:311)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.removeInvalid(ProviderList.java:332)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.Providers.getFullProviderList(Providers.java:165)
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getProviders(Security.java:457)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.computeOidTable(AlgorithmId.java:637)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.oidTable(AlgorithmId.java:627)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.algOID(AlgorithmId.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:595)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.getTimestamp(SignerInfo.java:545)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:595)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:759)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1038)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:870)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:786)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1976)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.initPhase3(System.java:2074)
ProviderConfig: Loading provider SunEC
ProviderConfig: Error loading provider SunEC
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:248)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:242)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.loadAll(ProviderList.java:315)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.removeInvalid(ProviderList.java:332)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.Providers.getFullProviderList(Providers.java:165)
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getProviders(Security.java:457)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.computeOidTable(AlgorithmId.java:637)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.oidTable(AlgorithmId.java:627)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.algOID(AlgorithmId.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:595)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.getTimestamp(SignerInfo.java:545)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.SignerInfo.verify(SignerInfo.java:318)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS7.verify(PKCS7.java:595)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:759)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1038)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:870)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:786)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1976)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.initPhase3(System.java:2074)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getSystemClassLoader cannot be called during the system class loader instantiation
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1932)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader.<init>(ProviderConfig.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader.<clinit>(ProviderConfig.java:313)
    ... 38 more
ProviderList: Disabling ThreadLocal providers
ProviderList: ThreadLocal providers: [SUN, SunRsaSign, SunEC, SunJCE]
ProviderList: Disabling ThreadLocal providers
ProviderList: ThreadLocal providers: [SUN, SunRsaSign, SunEC, SunJCE]
ProviderList: Disabling ThreadLocal providers
D:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.weaver_1.9.6.202103162301.jar;D:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.runtime_1.9.6.202103162301.jar
org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.WeavingURLClassLoader
Hello World!
ProviderConfig: Loading provider SunJGSS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:248)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(ProviderConfig.java:242)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList.tryGet(ProviderList.java:511)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList$ServiceList$1.hasNext(ProviderList.java:565)
    at java.base/java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getSignature(JsseJce.java:202)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.JsseJce$EcAvailability.<clinit>(JsseJce.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(JsseJce.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:1079)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:941)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:384)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:580)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1918)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1894)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
    at org.pmd.bug.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

It seems to me that when the system class loader is initialized to `org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.WeavingURLClassLoader` in `Classloader#initSystemClassLoader` some steps later loading of all Security providers is triggered somehow which in turn needs access to the system class loader (which isn't fully initialized yet).
This leeds to this part of the log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getSystemClassLoader cannot be called during the system class loader instantiation
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1932)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader.<init>(ProviderConfig.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader.<clinit>(ProviderConfig.java:313)
```

Later with the call to SSLContext.getInstance("TLS") in the app, the sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader is needed again but this time fails with the NoClassDefFoundError.

***Do you think my analysis is correct?***

***Is this a (potential) bug in OpenJDK 11.0.11?***

***Is there a possible workaround for this problem?***

**Update (06.07.21):**

[I found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477695/336169) how to see the complete command-line invocation resulting from the Eclipse launch configuration. Here it is:

```
C:\Programme\Java\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe -Djava.security.debug=jca -Djava.system.class.loader=org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.WeavingURLClassLoader -Daj.class.path=D:\workspace\sts490\edrewemaster\example-demo\target\classes;D:\workspace\sts490\edrewemaster\example-demo\target\test-classes;D:\repo\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.9.6\aspectjrt-1.9.6.jar;D:\workspace\sts490\edrewemaster\example-demo\target\classes -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -classpath D:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.weaver_1.9.6.202103162301.jar;D:\sts-4.11.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.aspectj.runtime_1.9.6.202103162301.jar org.pmd.bug.Main
```

When I run it from the command line like this (with java instead of javaw), I also get the exception. When I use an older Java version (11.0.10) like

```
C:\Programme\Java\11.0.10_9_adopt\jdk-11.0.10+9\bin\java ...
```

it works.

So Eclipse seems to replace the system class loader for LTW. Is there a way to tell Eclipse to use LTW with the javaagent solution? Perhaps this would circumvent the issue?

**I think I found a workaround: Don't use the Eclipse launch configuration of type "AspectJ Load-Time Weaving Application", instead use a normal Java Application launch config and pass the "-javaagent" flag to enable LTW, e.g.**

```
-javaagent:D:\repo\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.6\aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: I tried running your code with the AspectJ LTW agent from both IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse 2021-06 on JDK 11 and 16, no problems. I have no STS, use Oracle JDK, a developer build of AJDT adjusted to more recent Eclipse versions and therefore cannot match your exact setup, but I guess in principle there should not be any problem. What happens if you change the Java version or run the application from outside STS? You need to try and isolate the problem.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for looking into this. This issue only occurs with 11.0.11, earlier Java 11 versions are ok. I clarified this in the question. Which Java version did you try? Could you double check with 11.0.11?  Thanks!
AJDT version is latest from Marketplace, see console output: "1.9.6.202103162301"

Comment: I saw your versions and already explained that mine are different. My AJDT is also more recent than the marketplace version, because I built it myself. Sorry that I am too busy to exactly rebuild your situation locally, I just wanted to give you quick feedback, explaining my expectation that it normally should work. So if it does not, maybe there is really something "wrong" (of different than before) about 11.0.11. If I get around to trying, I will let you know my findings. If for now you could simply use another version in order to unblock yourself, please do.

Comment: No problem if you don't have time to try with 11.0.11. Your help is appreciated.
Yes, with 11.0.10 i can get around this problem, but then I get into another problem related to multi-release jar files on the classpath. Do you maybe know if AspectJ LTW honors the correct classpath dealing with multiple versions of classes in a mr-jar?
If not, I'll try to build another question/sample for that new problem...

Comment: I tried with Oracle JDK 11.0.11 and had no problems, so maybe it is just OpenJDK (where did you download it from?) or is it STS vs. my normal Eclipse, or the AspectJ or the AJDT version. Too many factors to test. Can you please try to run the application as a normal Java application and simply put the Java agent on the command line manually? Ideally, also test outside of STS, e.g. from a batch file or from Maven. I need something reproducible in order to help you.

Comment: As for JMS, AspectJ only has basic support, which is not particularly well-tested. I would guess that multi-release JARs have not been tested, but I can look into it if you provide me with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That the JDK minor version should make a difference, is strange though.

Comment: I tested with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11.9-hotspot, Oracle JDK build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194 and Zulu11.48+21-CA (build 11.0.11+9-LTS (which I added to the question.). I found out how to see the complete command-line generated by Eclipse and tested this with the same result. Please see my updated question above. Eclipse doesn't seem to use the javaagent, but replacement of the system class loader.

Comment: I will create a separate question for the multi-release JAR problem to separate these issues.

Comment: Yes, which is why before I asked you: _"Can you please try to run the application as a normal Java application and simply put the Java agent on the command line manually?"_ This was also the hint telling you how to run LTW in the alternative way you were asking about before, but I see you found out already.

Comment: I tried to replicate the commandline you copied from the debugger. It works on JDKs 11.0.10, 11.0.11, 13.0.3, 16. I cannot replicate your problem. Those files like `org.aspectj.weaver_1.9.6.202103162301.jar` - where can I download them separately? I want to see if they are any different than the regular AspectJ 1.9.6 files. Maybe you can send me MG5 or SHA-1 checksums of both the weaver and runtime JARs.

Comment: I searched for "AJDT" in the Eclipse Marketplace and installed it from there into STS 4.11:
AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.4.202103162301

AspectJ Compiler 1.9.6.202103162301

Equinox Weaving SDK 1.2.0.202103162301
I don't know where to download them separately.

Comment: BTW, with the javaagent option, my multi-release JAR problem went away, too.

Comment: One difference is, that the Eclipse packaged AspectJ JARS are signed whereas the "normal" AspectJ JARS from Maven Central are not. This might trigger verification of the signer info and loading of the security providers when using the Eclipse packaged AspectJ JARS and replacing the system class loader for LTW.

Comment: There we go, Holger! It is actually about the Eclipse-packages JARs. I downloaded them directly from the [Eclipse update site](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/410/dev/update/ajdt-e410-2.2.4.202103162301/plugins/) and can now reproduce the issue, exactly as you said with JDK 11.0.11, while it works normally with 11.0.10, 13.0.2 and 16. With the regular 1.9.6 and 1.9.7 files from Maven Central, this problem does not occur. So we have isolated the problem more now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few experiments and found out that the problem

- is completely unrelated to AspectJ,
- is completely unrelated to Java agents in general,
- occurs if and only if

  - `-Djava.system.class.loader` is used and
  - the system class loader in question is found in a signed JAR and
  - the application runs on JDK 11.0.11 (not 11.0.10 or any other JDK 9-16 I tested).

As soon as I remove the JAR signature from the `META-INF` directory, it also works on JDK 11.0.11. IMO, this is a regression bug in the JDK and should be fixed. Here is a minimal test case:

```java
package org.acme.app;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

```java
package org.acme.loader;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

  public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    byte[] b = loadClassFromFile(name);
    return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
  }

  private byte[] loadClassFromFile(String fileName) {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
      .getResourceAsStream(fileName.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class");
    byte[] buffer;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int nextValue = 0;
    try {
      while ((nextValue = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        byteStream.write(nextValue);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    buffer = byteStream.toByteArray();
    return buffer;
  }
}
```

Please make sure that both classes are in different packages, otherwise later the JVM will complain about not both of them being signed.

We are in the base directory, the source code is in folder `src`.

```
# Compile source files (JDK used for compilation is unimportant)
javac --release 8 src\org\acme\app\Main.java src\org\acme\loader\CustomClassLoader.java

# Create JAR containing custom class loader
jar cf CustomClassLoader.jar -C src org\acme\loader\CustomClassLoader.class

# Create signing key (default keystore has password 'changeit')
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias test-user

# Sign JAR (default keystore has password 'changeit')
jarsigner CustomClassLoader.jar test-user

# Run dummy application, setting custom class loader from JAR as system class loader
"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\java.exe" -Djava.security.debug="jca" -Djava.system.class.loader=org.acme.loader.CustomClassLoader -cp "CustomClassLoader.jar;src" org.acme.app.Main
```

Vary the path to `java.exe` in order to see that the problem really only occurs on JDK 11.0.11.

---

**Update:** I just filed a JDK bug report with Oracle (internal review ID 9070863). As soon as I hear from them and the bug is in the public bug database, I will update this answer again.

**Update 2:** Bug report [JDK-8270170](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8270170) is now visible, after it was verified.

Comment: Many thanks for wrapping up this issue. I fully agree with the analysis. I would have written a summary myself at the weekend. ;-)
The workaround/recommendation is to use the javaagent approach for LTW.
Extra kudos for filing a corresponding JDK bug!

Comment: Linked answer to bug report JDK-8270170.